# Как обойти защиту от XSS на своем сайте админу?

Tags: laravel, youtube-api, xss

Сайт делаю на Laravel 5.1, php 5.6.

В админке сделал пунки для сохранения HTML блоков на сайте(всякие коды баннеров, рекламные блоки, телефоны и т.д.). Все нормально работает и сохраняет.

НО! когда я пытаюсь вставить видео из Youtube через iframe код то сайт не сохраняет и в логах пишет:

```
[Thu Jan 07 11:11:10 2016] [error] [client 212.154.154.216] ModSecurity:  [file "/etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo/07_XSS_XSS.conf"] [line "96"] [id "212280"] [rev "1"] [msg "COMODO WAF: Cross-site Scripting (XSS) Attack"] [data "Matched Data: <iframe found within ARGS:html: <p><iframe src=\\x22https://www.youtube.com/embed/kepmgixlixw?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0\\x22 width=\\x22754\\x22 height=\\x22200\\x22 frameborder=\\x220\\x22 allowfullscreen=\\x22allowfullscreen\\x22></iframe></p>"] [severity "CRITICAL"] Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "< {0,1}iframe" at ARGS:html. [hostname "e-conditer.kz"] [uri "/blocks/saqtau"] [unique_id "Vo3zbn8AAAEADKwOSKkAAAAJ"]
```

Т.е. не сохраняет именно iframe. Как мне обойти его? я все таки должен добавлять видео на сайт.

Answer (score 1):

```
header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");
```

Но лучше такого не делать если не уверены что контент будете заполнять не вы

Comment: получается видео с Youtube нельзя добавлять вообще?

Comment: можно, у меня была такая проблема, это связано с iframe, пробуй зайти на сайт youtube -> Shared(под видео) -> Embed, там скопируйте не ссылку, а целый iframe

Comment: но чтобы видео показался нужно же весь Iframe. Зачем мне ссылка?

Да я понимаю что тег iframe я могу сам дописать указав ссылку с Youtube. Но я не знаю размер видео(ширину и высоту). Для того чтобы его узнать надо делать запрос к API youtube. Но это не то что мне нужно